# How much can you minimize the overlap of intervals?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I'm wondering about the following (sorry I invented some terminology):

> Consider a collection of intervals $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^n$ such that $I_k\subset[0,1]$ and $|I_k|>1/3$. Define the order of $x\in[0,1]$ as the maximum number of $I_k$ which contain $x$ and have an intersection of length at least $\epsilon$. Compute
>   $$F(n,\epsilon):=\inf\sup_{x\in[0,1]}order(x)$$
>   where the infimum is taken over all the possible collections $\{I_k\}$.

In other words, how much can you minimize the $\epsilon$-overlaps of $n$ intervals of length bigger than $1/3$? I don't expect this to be solvable exactly so I'd be interested if anyone knows of or has a reference for any lower bounds, asymptotics, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify: In "the maximum number of $I_k$ which contain $x$ and have an intersection of length at least $\epsilon$", the intersection is over the entire subcollection (whose maximal size is the order), not pairwise?

Comment: The intersection of the entire subcollection has length at least $\epsilon$, sorry if it's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We can consider intervals of length $\frac{1}{3}$ only, provided that we are only interested in the lower bound.** The rationale is as follows. Let $I_>$ be a collection of intervals of length $> \frac{1}{3}$ and $|I_>| = n$. We can shrink each interval in $I_>$ by cutting off one end such that the length of the interval becomes equal to $\frac{1}{3}$. Let us denote the resulting collection as $I$. Then,
$$
\texttt{order}(I_>, \epsilon, x) \geq \texttt{order}(I, \epsilon, x)
$$
and hence
$$
\inf_{I_>}\sup_{0\leq x \leq 1}\texttt{order}(I_>, \epsilon, x) \geq \inf_I \sup_{0\leq x \leq 1} \texttt{order}(I, \epsilon, x)
$$

---

Let $I = \{I_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a collection of intervals and $I_i = [a_i, b_i]$ where $0 \leq a_i < a_i + \frac{1}{3} = b_i \leq 1$. W.L.O.G, assume $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_n$. For simplicity, let $r = \sup_{0\leq x \leq 1}\texttt{order}(I, \epsilon, x)$ for some $\epsilon < \frac{1}{3}$.

By definition of $r$,

- there exists a subcollection $\{I_i, I_{i+1}, \cdots, I_{i+r-1}\}$ such that $b_i - a_{i+r-1} = a_i + \frac{1}{3} - a_{i+r-1} \geq \epsilon$ (note that $I_i \cap I_{i+1} \cap \cdots \cap I_{i+r-1} = [a_{i+r-1}, b_i]$). Therefore, $a_{i+r-1} - a_i \leq \frac{1}{3} - \epsilon$.
- moreover, $a_{i+r} - a_i > \frac{1}{3} - \epsilon$ for $1 \leq i \leq n - r$.

Specially,
\begin{align}
a_{1+r} - a_1 &> \frac{1}{3} - \epsilon \\
a_{1+2r} - a_{1+r} &> \frac{1}{3} - \epsilon \\
a_{1+3r} - a_{1+2r} &> \frac{1}{3} - \epsilon \\
&\cdots
\end{align}
Let $c$ be the minimum integer such that $1 + cr > n$, we then have
$$
\frac{2}{3} \geq a_{1+(c-1)\cdot r} - a_1 > (\frac{1}{3} - \epsilon)\cdot (c-1) > (\frac{1}{3} - \epsilon) \cdot (\frac{n-1}{r} - 1)
$$
As a result,
$$
r > \frac{(\frac{1}{3} - \epsilon)\cdot(n-1)}{1 - \epsilon}
$$

Comment: This is a very good bound! Unless someone suggests something tighter, I'll accept the answer.